# Firebase linker warnings in Xcode 11.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, linker-warning

Firebase (6.25.0)
FirebaseAnalytics (6.5.1)
FirebaseCore (6.7.1)
macOS Catalina (10.15.4)
Xcode 11.5

I updated the Firebase SDK via CocoaPods in my Xcode workspace and started getting several Xcode linker (ld) warnings that all boil down to variants of these two:

1. ld: warning: instance method method-name in category from archive-filename/object-filename conflicts with same method from another category

example:

```
ld: warning: instance method 'registeredInstallationWithJSONData:date:error:' in category from /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-frvtlafpkeliluaxjjycfjdpboxi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations/libFirebaseInstallations.a(FIRInstallationsItem+RegisterInstallationAPI 2.o) conflicts with same method from another category
```

2. ld: warning: meta method method-name in category from archive-filename/object-filename conflicts with same method from another category

example:

```
ld: warning: meta method 'validStringOrNilForKey:fromDict:' in category from /Users/andy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-frvtlafpkeliluaxjjycfjdpboxi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myapp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations/libFirebaseInstallations.a(FIRInstallationsItem+RegisterInstallationAPI 2.o) conflicts with same method from another category
```

I've tried clean builds and cleaning/reinstalling the pod cache but continue to get these warnings. These don't seem to harm execution of the app, but I'd like to clear them up. I recently updated to Xcode to 11.5 so it's possible that could be a factor (Xcode 11.5 also started showing [other types of linker warnings for the Ads SDK](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/130677) ).

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/25493422/556617

Comment: @PaulBeusterien Thanks! the marked "best" answer to that question inspired me to deintegrate all pods from my workspace and reinstall them. That cleared up these Firebase linker warnings. (the invalid debug info warnings still persist for the Ads SDK, but that appears to be an Xcode 11.5 bug).